# Wordbooker cURL error

Tags: wordpress, curl

I am using Wordpress V 3.4.2, while trying to install Wordbooker, it keeps giving error:

*Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_version() in /data/www/.../plugins/wordbooker/wordbooker.php on line 111*

I do have cURL activated.

```
curl -V/    
curl 7.21.4 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/1.0.0d zlib/1.2.5 libidn/1.20
    Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
    Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

I could not find sufficient information on Wordbooker's forums, please help me!

Comment: the command line curl and the curl module that php uses are different.  Have you checked to see if the curl php module is installed and loaded?

Comment: Yes. I ran a phpinfo() and cURL is installed and active..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from http://support.it-mate.co.uk/?mode=KB&kbid=32

**Symptoms**

You receive "Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_version()" when running a PHP application that requires cURL

**Cause**

This error occurs when cURL is not installed or not enabled.

**Resolution**

Check cURL (php_curl.dll) is installed and enabled in php.ini.

Checking php_curl.dll exists

Open your PHP extensions directory (usually C:\PHP\ext) and locate php_curl.dll

This file is usually included in the latest PHP installation file from php.net

**Checking cURL is enabled**

To do this, open php.ini and locate the following line;

extension=php_curl.dll

If it begins with a semi colon (;), remove the semi colon, save the file, then re-start your server.